# Hiding div only in CSS

Tags: css

I have a situation similar to this:

On first page of a website

```
<div class="div1">

 <div class="child"> </div>
</div>

<div class = "div2">
</div>
```

On some other pages:

```
<div class="div1">

<div class="child"> </div>
<div class="child"> </div>
<div class="child"> </div>
</div>

<div class = "div2">
</div>
```

Basically, I want to hide div2 only for a div that has only one child.

I can use only CSS.

Is it possible to target only that specific one child div and hide "div2" using only CSS?

Thanks

What I recall is that I tried doing something similar in the past for div that had 6 children.

(changing width)

```
/* six items */
div.answer:first-child:nth-last-child(6),
div.answer:first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ div {
width: calc(50% - 14px) !important;
}
```

The trick was that we influence the first child and all of its siblings when the first child was also the sixth child from the end.

Comment: _"The trick was that we influence the first child and all of its siblings when the first child was also the sixth child from the end."_ - but that approach won't work here - because the div that you actually want to hide, is not a _sibling_ following those children you want to count.

Comment: Maybe `div:not(:has(div + div)) + div`? `:has` isn't completely supported yet but getting there.

Comment: Yes, I think it will have to involve `:has()` - with the caveat, that this still does not work in Firefox (only if the user specifically enables it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **:has()** Pseudo Class for this effect.

```
.div1:has( .child:only-child ) + div2 {
    display: none;
}
```

For more study about **:has** pseudo class, you can use this [link](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/).

Comment: You're missing a `.` in front of your `div2`, but that looks like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

As of today there is

> No all browser supported method for this

Firefox still doesn't natively supports :has() by default. (not recommended)

For this to actually work, you will have to modify your HTML a little.
All you will have to do is to make the .div2 a child of .div1 and then this css should do the trick:

> .child + .div2:not(.child + .child + .div2){
> background-color: pink;
> }

It selects a .div2 class which is a sibling of .child class but not is a sibling of .child class which is a sibling of another .child class.

This simplifies to selecting a .div2 class with only one .child class.

Code snippet:

```css
.child + .div2:not(.child + .child + .div2){
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="child">first</div>
  <div class="child">second</div>
  <div class="child">third</div>
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>


<div class="div1">
  <div class="child">first</div>
  <div class="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```